# What is the difference between an alias queue and a local queue?

Tags: xml, queue, jms, message-queue, messaging

In terms of JMS I just need a brief overview on how they are different. ie. does the alias receive the same messages that the local one does.

Comment: another use for Logging MQ Messages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828768/logging-mq-messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@toop: concept of alias is similar in concept as we have jndi reference name to actual jndi mapping in j2ee application....basically alias is alias name given to a queue...developer uses alias queue name in his code but actual queue can be pointed by alias queue..so administrator may change actual queue but developer's code will not change...

another good use of alias queue is that in case different applications want to work with the same queue in different ways. For e.g. assign different default priorities or different default persistence values