# Logging MQ Messages

Tags: logging, ibm-mq

I want to log messages that come into MQ Queue to database/file or another logging queue and I can not modify existing code. Are there any methods to implement some kind of message logging utility that will act like HTTP sniffer? Or maybe MQ have some built-in finctionality to log messages?

Thanks in advance for your ansers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is possible by creating ALIAS QUEUE that points to a topic.

Assuming `RECV.Q` as the queue that your application currently receives messages from and processes.

1) First create a topic, say `LOG.TO.DATABASE`.
2) Then create an alias queue `ALIAS.LOG.TO.DATABASE` with `Base object` set to `LOG.TO.DATABASE` and set `Base Type` as `Topic`.
3) Then create a local queue `LOG.TO.DATABASE.Q`
4) Create a durable subscription, `SUB.FOR.RECV.Q` that points to `RECV.Q` as destination.
5) Create another durable subscription `SUB.FOR.LOG.TO.DABASE` that points to `LOG.TO.DATABASE.Q` as destination

Now the sender application need to put messages to `ALIAS.LOG.TO.DATABASE`. Since the alias queue actually points to topic, the messages gets published onto `LOG.TO.DATABASE`. To this topic we have two subscriptions registered, so both will get the same message. Your consumer application will continue to work as is whereas a new application can be written to process messages from other subscription.

Answer (score 2):

Here are commands of @Shashi's comment:

```
DEFINE QLOCAL ('RECV.Q')
DEFINE TOPIC('LOG.TO.DB') TOPICSTR('DBLOG')
DEFINE QALIAS('ALIAS.LOG.TO.DB') TARGET('LOG.TO.DB') TARGTYPE(TOPIC)
DEFINE QLOCAL('LOG.TO.DB.Q')
DEFINE SUB('SUB.FOR.RECV.Q') DEST('RECV.Q') TOPICOBJ('LOG.TO.DB')
DEFINE SUB('SUB.FOR.LOG.TO.DABASE') DEST('LOG.TO.DB.Q') TOPICOBJ('LOG.TO.DB')
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use (free) open source project called Message Multiplexer (MMX) http://www.capitalware.biz/mmx_overview.html

If you need may queues to be logged/audited then you may want to look at MQ Auditor (it is a commercial product): http://www.capitalware.biz/mqa_overview.html

Comment: Misleading answer. The product in question is neither open source nor free. Its costs 999$.